# FB like button Joomla

Tags: css, video, joomla, facebook-like, internet-explorer-9

I am using FB like button in Joomla. This is the address of my website http://www.kaefiggefluester.de.

For fb-like button, I am using custom html module with fb social plugin code and then loading it in user4 position which i defined in the template myself.

Now there are three different problems that I am facing.

1. In IE 9, before the fb-like button loads, it displays a white line. It disappears after the button is loaded. I am not facing this problem in Firefox.
2. Also, when loading the page in IE, it sometimes distorts the page. I know that one posts said that I should look for any script that distorts  tag, however i face this problem only if I have facebook plugin enabled. IF I remove the fb-like code from Custom Joomla module, it works fine.
3. I have a component from Videoflow. I dont know exactly how it works but fb-like button doesnt work on the sampe page as this component. However it is working in IE but with wrong language. That is, my defined language for the button is DE (German) and so in rest of the pages it displays "Gefaellt mir." However, In KG TV it shows "Like." ... So this suggest that there is something wrong with loading of the script. However, this is happening in IE only. In firefox it is not loading at all.

If you think i should share some code, please let me know because there are so many files and I dont know which to share.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or using the Chrome equivalent to help you during the development of your website. You can then use the console to view if there are any problems. For example currently your website has these problems which might be the reason you are having the issues you mentioned:

[image]

Comment: Ok. Thankz a lot. I am a new developer andwhT i have learned is by myself.  I am using firebug and  have seen these errors but i dont think they mattered while some pages seemed to work as desired. I will try fixing all of errors ... still thankss a lot for ur commnt.